"in other words" - Can this be used as a subordinating conjunction?

One of the foundational questions regarding any talent or ability is
whether it is innate or learned–in other words, are we born musical,
or can musicality and creativity be taught?

Is this a run-on sentence?  Or is this grammatically correct?
Does the em dash somehow connect the 2 clauses?
Can an em dash be used in place of a semi-colon?

Merriam-Webster has << in other words
[idiom]
—used to introduce a statement that repeats what has been said in a different and usually a simpler or more exact way
"She said the movie was a bit predictable. In other words, she didn't like it." >> (repunctuated slightly) It is quite acceptable to replace the full stop (and new sentence) with a dash before the paraphrasing independent clause.  A semicolon is also acceptable.

The comment says so. Semicolon or dash? shows that either can be used to join (semantically related) independent clauses, and 'in other words' is a parenthetical that may be placed between suitable independent clauses.

Which “grammatical rule” do you feel this violates as spoken–or “orthographic rule”, as written? Could you please tell us where you found this rule?

Thanks for your help.  I guess I'm wrong, but I thought that an em dash was a comma with a bigger pause.  I didn't realize that it could also be used to connect 2 independent clauses.  I learn something new every day.

This is 2 questions in one, which we discourage. Your first question – about whether it's a run-on sentence – seems to flow from your unfamiliarity with how the dash is used, which is the subject of your second question. If you replace the dash with a semi-colon, does your first question still need answering? And your second question doesn't really belong on our site, since punctuation – and especially dashes – is a matter of style for which guidance is best sought in your preferred style manual.

@EdwinAshworth Yes, but the 'indicator' "in other words" is part of the supplement. It serves to clarify the nature of its semantic relationship to the anchor ("whether it is innate or learned").

@ChappoHasn'tForgotten: I don't agree that punctuation should be off topic. And I certain don't agree that style should be off topic! It is in fact one of the major topic of this site, why people come here.

@EdwinAshworth You voted to close this because it can be looked up in a dictionary. But how? Where can the poster easily find this information? I mean, yes, perhaps he could look at the (loooong) entry for word and see whether in other words was listed, and whether it had a syntactic label; but that is only part of the question. He cannot find in that entry the fact that, in this case, it is the dash which is responsible for his puzzlement.

@Cerberus I explained this in the comment.

@EdwinAshworth: It does not explain how all of the question is easily found in a dictionary. The mere meaning of the phrase in other words is by no means enough.

@Cerberus The dictionary shows the use of this phrase to introduce a related independent clause. The duplicate deals with the other question, the use of punctuation like dashes to join two independent clauses. An introductory phrase in the second sentence in the two-sentence variant is merely lower-cased.

The heart of the matter is that a dash interrupts the sentence, because—see? You can interrupt an incomplete sentence—turning it into an anacoluthon—with a dash, and begin a new sentence, or just add a few words less than a sentence or clause.
You may or may not resume the old sentence after a second, matching dash, turning the part between dashes into parenthesis, just as when you enclose something in brackets, or in commas.
Note that overuse of dashes is not good style; but, used sparingly, they are beyond reproach except in very formal language.
In your case, the phrase in other words is a red herring: it is an ordinary adverbial phrase. If you left it out, your sentence would still work and have the same syntax.

I'd say that the preposition phrase "in other words" is an indicator serving to clarify the nature of its semantic relationship to the anchor ("whether it is innate or learned"). It's part of the supplement "in other words, are we born musical ...".

@BillJ: Yes, but does that make a difference with respect to the structure of the sentence here, "subordinating conjunction" and such?

Yes, because it shows that it is part of the supplement. You said it was an adverbial phrase, which I wouldn't go along with, though I accept that supplements are a sub-type of adjunct in clause structure. The supplement in full is, of course, in other words, are we born musical, or can musicality and creativity be taught?

@BillJ: It is a bit hard to follow because I don't know all of your terminology, so I don't know how such things as 'supplements' are defined.

Em dashes can correctly connect two independent clauses in place of a semicolon or colon. In other situations, they can also replace commas or parentheses. They can effectively connect sentence components of any length—though whether to use them in every situation where a comma or semicolon would suffice is another matter.
“In other words” is just a transitional phrase that can be placed parenthetically within an independent clause, typically at the start. It links the clauses semantically, but not grammatically.
Side note: the dash in your quoted example is actually an en dash (–), not an em dash (—). So, technically, your sentence is incorrect. Some guides recommend a spaced en dash in place of an em dash, but an unspaced en dash is never used for this purpose.

Outside of the United States, the English-speaking world, such as in the UK, mostly uses a spaced en dash, not an em dash. So you cannot say an en dash is "wrong".

@tchrist: Hmm would you really say Brits don't use spaceless m-dashes in older print?

@tchrist “Some guides recommend a spaced en dash in place of an em dash, but an unspaced en dash is never used for this purpose.” The issue is the en dash without any spaces.

@Cerberus-ReinstateMonica Yes, certainly old typeset books employed a great variety of longer dashes seldom seen today. Focusing on what the dash is doing functionally simply strikes me as more educational than worrying about lengths and spacing from random internet faux typesetting.

Yes: an indicator serving to clarify the nature of its semantic relationship to the anchor ("whether it is innate or learned").

@Cerberus-ReinstateMonica Not just Brits but most of the English-speaking world beyond North America. In any case, punctuation is primarily a matter of style, and styles change. For example, in Australia an address used to be written in the form "110 James-street", but this approach disappeared about 60 years ago. We never used to insert a capital after a colon the way they do in the US style, but this monstrous aberration is now creeping into our publications.  English orthography is almost as dynamic as the language itself.

@tchrist: That was also my point of view.

@ChappoHasn'tForgotten: A capital after a colon? I don't remember seeing that—sweet baby Perseus. I do seem to recall seeing m-dash without spaces in British literature, though. In the rest of Europe, perhaps not. Certainly not now.

@tchrist ... I certainly recall reading Jane Austen's profligate use of em dashes two centuries ago. Sometimes it seemed like she couldn't write a paragraph without salting it liberally with those.

@Robusto Sometimes you find two-em and three-em dashes in those really old novels. Hence U+2E3A ‭ ⸺  TWO-EM DASH, U+2E3B ‭ ⸻  THREE-EM DASH, etc.
